# Using Tabs and Router in Angular and Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When I click on a tab, it gets me to the html that I need but the tabs disappears. It doesn't go in to the tab content of the tab. It seems to load another page. Please see my code below
**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Enventmanager</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UserComponent,
    SomeComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'user',
        component: UserComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SignInComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignUpComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**user.component.html**

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" routerLink='/signup' role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" routerLink='/signin' role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" routerLink='/signup' role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

I am using Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4. Can you help? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples), an angular powered bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Reason is they have different routes, all of them are parent

better solution is moving

**user.component.html** template content to **AppComponent**

Or you could try using **children** https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: So there is no need to import all the script files mentioned by Bernhard?

Comment: Yes, unless you forgot to import them

Comment: I am sorry, do you mean I have to have all those files in my .angular-cli.json => "scripts": [ ... ]?

Comment: Yes or you could just simply place the **maxcdn** file into your index.html, refer [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: That cdn is a lot simpler I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the Bootstrap javascript files and it's dependencies into your **angular.cli.json** file. From then first Bootstrap is fully working in an angular app. Before it's just the visual/css part which works.

And keep in mind **jquery** and **popper** is required by bootstrap and is required as well to avoid errors.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/alert.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/button.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/carousel.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tab.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/popover.js"
  ]
```

Comment: Tether was required for Bootstrap 4 alpha. It has been replaced in the current version by Popper, which means that Tether isn't needed. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: @Klooven thanks that showed up beeing active here also improves existing projects I'll fix that in the answer above

Comment: I am installing the dependencies. Thank you.

Comment: I had already included the scripts in my .angular-cli still I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: do not include js\jquery file, instead use a component library as ngx-bootstrap or ng-bootstrap.